# How do you programmatically center the alignment of a text label for iOS?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I want to set the alignment of a text label, how can I do that?

Answer (score 48):

I think there are the answers who helped you out. The correct way to do this is:

```
yourLabelName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

for more documentation you can read this:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel

In Swift :-

```
yourLabelName.textAlignment = .center
```

Here `.center` is `NSTextAlignment.center`

Comment: How about for the label in a tableview row? This is not working

Comment: do it like this cell.yourLabelName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

Comment: Not working: https://github.com/DaniSpringer/primes-fun/blob/master/Primes%20Fun/Controller/Random/RandomResultsViewController.swift

Answer (score 28):

Here you are,

```
yourLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter
```

**EDIT**

if you target above iOS6 use `NSTextAlignmentCenter` as `UITextAlignmentCenter` is depreciated

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 27):

This has changed as of iOS 6.0, [UITextAlignment has been deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextalignment). The correct way to do this now is:

```
yourLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Here is the NSTextAlignment enumerable that gives the options for text alignment:

Objective-C:

```
enum {
   NSTextAlignmentLeft      = 0,
   NSTextAlignmentCenter    = 1,
   NSTextAlignmentRight     = 2,
   NSTextAlignmentJustified = 3,
   NSTextAlignmentNatural   = 4,
};
typedef NSInteger NSTextAlignment;
```

Swift:

```
enum NSTextAlignment : Int {
    case Left
    case Center
    case Right
    case Justified
    case Natural
}
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextalignment)

Comment: @nari please accept this answer. Is the most up to date

Answer (score 9):

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

see [UILabel documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a multiline UILabel you should use a NSMutableParagraphStyle

```
   yourLabelName.numberOfLines = 0
   let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
   paragraphStyle.alignment = .Center

   let attributes : [String : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 15)!, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]

   let attributedText = NSAttributedString.init(string: subTitleText, attributes: attributes)
   yourLabelName.attributedText = attributedText
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3 and beyond it should be

```
yourlabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
```

Answer (score 2):

in swift 4:

```
 let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
 paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center

 // in Swift 4.2
 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your String", attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle:paragraphStyle])

 // in Swift 4.1--
 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your String", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle:paragraphStyle])

 let yourLabel = UILabel()
 yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Yourlabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: `UITextAlignmentCenter` is deprecated. Use `NSTextAlignmentCenter` as suggested below instead.