# Swift: Width constraints for dynamically resizable label

Tags: ios, swift, timer, interface-builder, constraints

Question regarding Auto Contraints and a dynamically resizable label.

I have a timer label that initally displays 00:00.00 (mins, seconds, milliseconds). When this timer reaches one hour or more I wish to resize the label to 00:00:00.00 while preserving the .Centerx constraint. Text justification on the label is set to Left so that the counting of numbers does not 'jitter' the text as it re-justifies to the different sizes of text.

I have my constraints set as the following:

[image: InitialConstraints]

Heres how the timer looks initially or when only counting minutes (up to 59:59:59)
[image: MinutesView]

And heres how it should look when Hours are involved in the count.

[image: HoursView]

Now the issue is that when hours are involved the width is dynamically resized (due to greater than constraint) and this causes the timer label to jitter as the different milliseconds are counted.

I desire to resize the label when counting hours to a width of 150 and back to 110 when hours are not counting - all while preserving the CenterX constant.

I have tried to programatically re-size the label when the count is in hours as so:

```
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: TimerLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 150)

 if Double(hours) != 0{
      TimerLabel.text = "\(strHours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds).\(strFraction)"

      TimerLabel.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
 }
```

Now in my IBAction func for the reset button I also have:

```
let widthConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: TimerLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 110)

 TimerLabel.removeConstraint(widthConstraint)
 TimerLabel.addConstraint(widthConstraint2)
```

However once the timer resets the label appears as follows:

[image]

The text is no longer centre in the view. I have also tried programming a width constraint for .CenterX in the reset function and that also produces no change in the reset label position.

Is there an easier way to do this Via Interface Builder? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try calling `setNeedsLayout()` after adding the additional constraint?

Comment: I did and it appears to have no difference. I wonder if setting the widthConstraint1 is removing the CenterX constraint from the label?

Comment: Perhaps. After you add the constraint, try printing all of them out with the `constraints()` method on `UIView`.

Comment: why don't you use constant for your label width

Comment: Having a constant width and text justified to centre causes the label to jitter onscreen as the timer counts up (since some numbers have different widths than others ex: 0 vs 1)

Comment: i think you need to use a fixed-width font to solve this properly

Comment: Good suggestions everyone. I think you are right Fonix. I'll look into that as a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fonix suggested the solution was to use a wixed width font which is easy to do in iOS9.

```
    let originalFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(26)
    let originalFontDescriptor = originalFont.fontDescriptor()

    let fontDescriptorFeatureSettings = [
        [
            UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: kNumberSpacingType,
            UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: kMonospacedNumbersSelector
        ]
    ]

    let fontDescriptorAttributes = [UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: fontDescriptorFeatureSettings]
    let fontDescriptor = originalFontDescriptor.fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes(fontDescriptorAttributes)
    let font = UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptor, size: 0)

    TimerLabel.font = font
```

Answer (score 2):

Try making the text label wider than it is and then centering the text. When more characters are added it will preserve the centre positioning.

Comment: The problem with centre positioning is that the timer label jitters onscreen as the timer counts up (since some numbers have different widths than others ex: 0 vs 1). I could also set the text to autosize but that is not ideal either. Im basically trying to replicate what the Apple Clock app does for its timer label.

Comment: Are you wanting to preserve the colons in their space?

Comment: Just wanting to preserve the Center Horizontally in view controller constraint. Colons don't really matter, sorry if this is a bit confusion/picky.

Comment: A couple of hacks try aligning the text to the right and increase the width of the UILabel left handle. At this point head to the size inspector and make sure your preferred width is defined and the explicit checkbox is checked. Update your constraints and run. If that doesn't work try making the UILabel background color the same as the interface and using that as the base for alignment. Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18928975/4891259